# Castle Windsor lifestyle in dotnet core web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, castle-windsor

What lifestyle should be used to replace PerWebRequest when using the Castle Windsor MS Adapter?

https://github.com/volosoft/castle-windsor-ms-adapter

Before dotnet core I would use the PerWebRequest lifestyle for almost all of the components in the container. Now that we are disconnected from IIS modules and http context, I want to ensure my components are being created and disposed when the web requests starts and ends.

Example:

```
container.Register(Component.For<MyEntityFrameworkContext>)
    .ImplementedBy<MyEntityFrameworkContext>()
    .LifestyleTransient());
```

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Core has it's own 'scoped' lifecycle, which is 'per request'. See it's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Usage example:

```
services.AddScoped<ICharacterRepository, CharacterRepository>();
```

You should do it inside `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup` class.

Comment: Is there any way to decouple from using the built in IoC container? We have multiple `endpoints` in this project and want to use a single container with a little more power.

Comment: Also, if we must use the built in container, what are the situations where we would use adapters such as this?

Comment: This is the design of AspNet Core's DI. But you can use LifestyleCustom<MsScopedLifestyleManager> to make it directly with Windsor API (this library makes it here: https://github.com/volosoft/castle-windsor-ms-adapter/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection/WindsorRegistrationHelper.cs#L105).

Comment: If you have multiple place to register dependencies, you have to do that abstraction yourself. Example: You can create an interface to register dependencies, find all implementations in ConfigureServices and call them.

Comment: Is it correct to say that the registrations in this gist provide the same functionality? https://gist.github.com/detroitpro/d6f05342f6b9817ed3269b0a6449c957

Comment: Yes, it has the same functionality.

Comment: using LifestyleCustom<MsScopedLifestyleManager> didn't work for me in ASP.NET Core. Castle resolved new transient instance instead of scoped instance (in https://github.com/volosoft/castle-windsor-ms-adapter/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection/MsScopedLifestyleManager.cs, it used "//Act as transient!" path). After some digging, I used not-yet-released Castle Windsor implementation - https://github.com/fir3pho3nixx/Windsor/blob/aspnet-core-windsor-final/docs/aspnetcore-facility.md (as of now you need to build castle windsor - git branch aspnet-core-windsor-final).