# How to make use of Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Lifestyle.PerWebRequest within Abp?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I want to register an existing instance of a class using life style PerWebRequest on JwtTokenValidated event handler. I am using ASP.NET Core OWIN. I am using AspNetBoilerplate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot [register an existing instance](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/f4c7a6fac4e8c42ba87b53090bf5e2b833876d34/docs/registering-components-one-by-one.md#register-existing-instance) using a specific lifestyle:

> ⚠ **Registering instance ignores lifestyle**: When you register an existing instance, even if you specify a lifestyle it will be ignored. Also registering instance will set the implementation type for you, so if you try to do it manually, an exception will be thrown.

You can register a type with the equivalent of `PerWebRequest` lifestyle:

```cs
IocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For<TestService>()
    .LifestyleCustom<MsScopedLifestyleManager>());
```

Then inject (or resolve) `TestService` in your event handler:

```cs
public MyEventHandler(TestService testService)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

Alternative: [Castle Windsor lifestyle in dotnet core web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592473/castle-windsor-lifestyle-in-dotnet-core-web-application)

> ASP.NET Core has it's own 'scoped' lifecycle, which is 'per request'. See it's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection
>
> Usage example:
>
> ```cs
> services.AddScoped<ICharacterRepository, CharacterRepository>();
> ```
>
> You should do it inside `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup` class.